# Moodle 3.2 scorm package not loading

Tags: javascript, xml, moodle, scorm

Moodle version 3.2.2

So, everything was working ok except my scorm TOC collapsing on click.

I couldn't ignore this and decided to "fix" it and ended up making a small change in the moodleinstallation\server\moodle\lib\yuilib\gallery\gallery-sm-treeview.js file - at line 696 I changed "value" to false from true for lazyrenderer -

lazyRender: {

```
        lazyAdd: false, // to ensure that the setter runs on init

        setter : '_setLazyRender',

        value  : true
```

Why I did this - There was a bug link where this patch / solution was made available for toc tree collapsing on click. The solution was like - set the lazy loading to false. Link - https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-45949

I wasnt able to understand the solution much so thought of making the change to see the impact.

But moodle didn't like it and stopped displaying the sorm package itself. In the API logging, buttons like LMSinitialize, LMScommit, etc are not working at all.

I reverted back to the original "value : true" but still not able to view the scorm package.

When I tried debugging through the browser (F12) I saw this error like - Cannot call method 'init' of undefined ...

Please help me in resolving this.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your missing a init method.  Any idea what script reports this?  Does the SCO work by itself?

Comment: Hi @mark, I replaced the scorm folder in the mod folder with the original scorm folder and things are back on track now. Thank you.